# Как интегрировать линк на внешний сайт?

Tags: c#, url, link

У меня есть программа - сам код и *ехе* от него. Запускаю *exe* — открывается *GUI*, на котором две кнопки, при нaжатии на которые программа выполняет то, чего от нее ожидают.

Требуется дополнить код так, чтобы и при нажатии на *exe*, а так же и на одну и на другую кнопку, открывался сайт (к примеру, `www.abcdefgh12345678.com`).

Как это сделать?

Comment: Process.Start("http://site.com") пробовали?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2):

`Process.Start("http://site.com")` - таким образом откроется сайт.